# Swagger 2.0 Accept-Language header as request parameter

Tags: http, http-headers, swagger, http-accept-language

I'm writing a specification for a http API using Swagger 2.0.

How can I define the [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header as a required header parameter for a path?

```
/aPath:
post:
  parameters:
    - in: header
      name: Accept-Language
      type: string
      enum: [de, en, es]
      required: true
  responses:
    200:
      description: The Best
      schema:
        type: string
```

[Documentation on header parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/) says

> Swagger specification has special keywords for some headers:
>   [image]

How can I use the keyword produces to define an Accept-Language header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is correct.

The page you mentioned talks about the [`Accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header, which is different from [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language).